# Primefaces draggable helper clone always revert

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use primefaces draggable and droppable. Everything is just fine so far. But when i use helper clone, although i indicated revert false, it always revert. Is there any idea about what I am doing wrong ?

```
<p:panel id="draggable1">
    <h:outputText value="Drag Me" />
    <p:draggable for="draggable1" 
                  revert ="false"  
                  helper="clone"/>
</p:panel>
```

By the way, draggable and droppable panel are in the different forms.

Comment: PF verision? and Please create a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) And are you sure your drop darget is a valid one?

Comment: Primefaces version 5.0. Yeah my drop target is valid because if I do not use helper, everything is just fine.